# avoid a new class every time you want to introduce new functionality?

Tags: c++, delphi, inheritance

In a huge complicated application I wonder if it is acceptable to not introduce a class just to implement a simple new functionality .

For example Class C and D inherits from A (among many other classes that also inherits from A).

If we want to introduce new shared functionality to C and D we can:

1) introduce a new class B(and implement in this class the shared functionality) between the parent class A and the 2 child classes C and D so B inherits from A while C and D inherit from B

2) add the functionality in the parent class A and add a flag to use this functionality only when the child is type of B or C (and make sure this way that we do not break something to the rest of the classes that inherit from A)

(in delphi I was thinking this flag as a published property, available at the object inspector, that makes really easy to include or exclude the functionality on each of the child classes)

Is it a bad practice to follow the second approach in order to avoid crazy multilevel complicated inheritance?

Comment: if it is c++ you can use multiple inheritance, in this case C and D continue inherit from A but they also inherit from B but in this case B does not have to inherit from A, to me this looks pretty neat.

Comment: Don't overuse inheritance. Ask your self if `B` actually _is a_ `A`, and `C` and `D` actually _are a_ `B`.

Comment: #2 is wrong. The parent class should know nothing about descendant classes at all, and adding the functionality to the parent and then using it or not depending on the class of the child is simply wrong from an OOP standpoint.

Comment: Moreover, in C++/Java/C# *and* Delphi you can use generics to define a class that uses the facets/services of another class specified at compile time - the entire STL is based on that. Inheritance shouldn't be used to provide shared functionality, it should only be used to model `is a` hierarchies

Comment: @Marco Multiinheritance is usefull when you want to joing functiuonality of two existing classes into one. But I belive thath the user is trying to add same functionality to two existing classes without them joining together into one. In this case inserting aditional class into existing inheritance change is the correct apporach.

Comment: If you're using Delphi and would otherwise choose C++ style multiple inheritance, another option would be to use interfaces and have classes C and D implement them, assuming interfaces would suit well to the overall architecture.

Comment: Have you considered composition rather than inheritance?

Comment: Without more details, I'm left scratching my head wondering what's wrong with a virtual method in the base class that can be overridden where needed. This is a simple approach that doesn't require either a new class nor that the parent class know anything about derived classes. Just define an empty body for the virtual method in the base class, then override it in whatever child classes need it and you'll be fine.  That said, if you really want to have a common implementation above classes C and D, then you'll need to introduce a class between A and C/D. The virtual method is still useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want new functionality, its better to create new class for this purpose. It becomes easy to modify the functionality later.
- As you said, "other classes also inherit from class A"; it might be the case that these classes don't want the functionality you are adding to class A. So, its better to create separate class.
- Although in 2nd approach you create flag to decide whether to use the functionality or not, I see it as overhead and might cause complexity ahead.

Creating separate class for separate functionality always helps. You can easily develop, maintain, update/modify the code; that's the beauty of Object Oriented Programming.
So, I would prefer option 1.